# input text blinks on iPad

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ipad

Im having problem with my site, i made a custom search text on `wordpress`, works good but on iPad it keeps blinking and i dont know why.

Here is the link

```
http://www.ibizapassion.net/product-category/bracelets/
```

What im doing wrong ? thanks !

Comment: I'm sure this is unrelated but I thought you should know you're missing an image file here: http://www.ibizapassion.netwp-content/themes/enfinity/images/assets/dots_hor.png

Comment: I loaded the site on my phone and I see the blinking in the search bar. As soon as I zoom in a little it goes away. Then it comes back if I zoom out again. It's almost like it's reloading the page over and over again when I'm zoomed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your search box is resizing the whole page, if only by a couple pixels, but then the page detects a page resizing, and redraws the search box, which then resizes the page, which then redraws the search box, ad infinitum. If you're looking to make it stop, I'd recommend specifying a min-width CSS property on the "body" element that is just a few pixels bigger than the page. It shouldn't take more than 20 pixels, and 2 pixels might do the trick.

Comment: Your right, my bad !
I've placed the form width more larger than the body container, i reduced a lot and now it doesn't do any blink anymore !

Thank you so much ! +1 and Marked !